# Duplicate current page in iframe: iframe wont load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am attempting to duplicate the current page in an iframe (to demo how the page will look on a mobile screen). But the page just wont load in the iframe - its just blank. Any idea whats wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var iframe = $('#my-iframe', window.parent.document);

    // if already in iframe
    if (iframe.length > 0) {
        $('<p>I\'m in an iframe!</p>').appendTo($('body'));

        // Now I can preview the website in mobile view!

        return;
    }
    else {
     $('<iframe>', {
           src: window.location.href,
           id:  'my-iframe',
           scrolling: 'no'
        }).appendTo($('body')).load();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>The below iframe should contain this page aswell</p>
```

**Edit:** Screenshot of outcome when running a local html file on Firefox; [image]

Comment: Is that `.load()` necessary? Not sure if that's replacing `src`.

Comment: @Jacob it has the same outcome for me if I have it in or not.

Comment: Is your JavaScript hosted in a different domain than your document domain? It might be a same origin policy issue. Do you have console errors?

Comment: @Jacob thanks for your advice. No console errors, weirdly the `I'm in an iframe!` gets attached outside the iframe (see above edit).

Comment: Maybe Firefox just doesn't show the errors? I see this when trying to reproduce in Chrome:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are rightly finicky when it comes to accessing the document of an iframe's parent. An easier way to see if you're in an iframe is to just check if the parent exists:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // if already in iframe
  if (window.parent && window.parent !== window) {
    $('<p>I\'m in an iframe!</p>').appendTo($('body'));
    return;
  } else {
    $('<iframe>', {
      src: window.location.href,
      id:  'my-iframe',
      scrolling: 'no'
    }).appendTo($('body')).load();
  }
});
```

Comment: that works for chrome and latest version of IE (edge?) but not Firefox or IE11. Any ideas for solutions on those?